# I need to save an XML file received by a request curl in JSON in my localhost with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am creating a curl request in JSON and an XML returns me in a position which I want to record in my localhost with PHP

```
$arrJson = array();
$arrJson["nit_emisor"] = $strNit;
$arrJson["correo_copia"] = "";
$arrJson["xml_dte"] = $strXML;

utf8_encode_array($arrJson);
// API de certificado recibe y retorna parametros JSON
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $strUrl,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  json_encode($arrJson),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "usuario: {$strUsuario}",
        "llave: {$strLlave}",
        "identificador: {$strCodigo}",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$arrReturn = json_decode($data, true);

$file = base64_decode($arrReturn["archivo"]);
```

I need save $file in a path in my localhost

I receive the XML file encode in base64 in a position called "archivo" this I want to save in a folder in my localhost with PHP

Comment: What is your question? Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried that isn't working so we may try to help you.

Comment: How can I record the file sent to me in my localhost

Comment: so you get a json file that you want to save as XML?

Comment: If there is an XML in a json position, I want to save it as a file in my directory